# get class instances from firebase db

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class

```
class A {
  var1: number;
  var2: number;

  sum(): number {
    return var1+var2;
  }
}
```

I'd like to persist instances of this class, and retrieve them from the database.

The problem is that what I retrieve from the database is of type Object, and while it has var1 and var2, calling `sum` is an error.

Is there a way to pass a constructor to firebase get operations? Is there a simple way to convert the returned Objects to MyClass?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database stores JSON data, not JavaScript objects. One of the differences between JSON data and JavaScript objects is the fact that JSON data can't have any functions defined on them.

The easiest way to get your objects back is probably to pass the JSON into a constructor and copying them with something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: I understand that the database itself stores JSON and not JS objects, I am asking is there a way to provide a constructor to FBDB's adaption layer